# Finding distance to edge of triangle with cartesian coordinates

Tags: geometry

I'm using a [ternary plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot) to represent the proportions between three descriptors.

As per the diagram below, the 'amount' of $B$ can be quantified as the proportion of the distance of the point $X$ from point $B$, divided by the total distance from $B$ to the opposite edge.

My question is about how to find the distance $f$ if I know the cartesian coordinates of the three corners of an equilateral triangle and the cartesian coordinates of the point $X$, which could be anywhere within the triangle.

I.e. the distance to the opposite edge.

I can find the distance $e$ by using the Pythagorean theorem as I know the offset of $X$ from $B$ and therefore know its position relative to $B$. However I'm not sure how to derive the distance $f$.

[image: Diagram of ternary plot]

Comment: Is $BX$ parallel to $AC$?

Comment: I'm looking for a general solution where X could be anywhere within the triangle, so BX is not necessarily perpendicular to AC, although it looks like it is in that particular example.

Comment: 1) Is the position of $X$ known? 2) Is $f$ the shortest distance or distance along the extension of $BX$?

Comment: X is known and $f$ is the extension of $BX$ to the edge of the triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any point $P$, let $x_P$ and $y_P$ be respectively the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of $P$.

### Steps to find $F$

1. Find the equation of the line passing through $B$ and $X$. With the known coordinates, it would be $(x_B-x_X)y=(y_B-y_X)x+(x_By_X-x_Xy_B)$.
2. Find the equation of the line passing through $A$ and $C$. With the known coordinates, it would be $(x_A-x_C)y=(y_A-y_C)x+(x_Ay_C-x_Cy_A)$.
3. With the equations, find the point of intersection between $BX$ and $AC$. Let that point be $Y$.
4. Find the distance of $Y$ from $X$ with the Phytagorean Theorem. That distance is $f$.